# 301 redirected page indexes with old URL still

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

It has been months since I redirected some pages and the URL has not updated in Google's index.

I am also unable to see a cached version of the site.

I found these pages using the `site:` feature

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I am sorry, but there is simply not enough information here to even guess. Can you add some detail, for example, your redirect code, when you redirected the pages, has googlebot visited the pages, etc.? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

> I found these pages using the `site:` feature

This is probably the reason why you are seeing these results, assuming all the (301 permanent) redirects have been correctly implemented and crawled by Google. A `site:` search is not a normal Google search and can often return URLs that are not returned in a normal search. Previously indexed URLs that are now redirected have been shown to be returned by a `site:` search.

However, try to find the same page in normal search and it's likely to be returned under the new/target URL (if at all), not the old redirected URL.

A related question regarding the *apparent* indexing of redirected short URLs:
[How to submit shortened URLs to Google so that they are included in the index](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88209/how-to-submit-shortened-urls-to-google-so-that-they-are-included-in-the-index)

Comment: Yes, you can see an example doing a site: search for moz's old domain, I'm pretty sure they would have done all the redirects correct, but Google still shows their old domain even after they migrated a couple of years ago:

https://www.google.co.th/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Aseomoz.com&oq=site%3Aseomoz.com&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.6211j0j7